# Try-Catch in IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, try-catch, ivalueconverter

Should `Try-Catch` block ever be used in `IValueConverter` classes with a WPF app ?
Sometimes I have been doing it but thinking if it makes any sense

```
public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        try {
            int result = [code removed...];
            return result;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I am looking for an approach for handling errors and validating parameters when `IValueConverter` is used.

Answer (score 2):

In general, The basic rule is **to catch exceptions if and only if you have a meaningful way of handling them** and I don't think it matters if it's in a `IValueConverter` or anywhere else.
But According to [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "The data binding engine does not catch exceptions that are thrown by a user-supplied converter. Any exception that is thrown by the Convert method, or any uncaught exceptions that are thrown by methods that the Convert method calls, are treated as run-time errors."
Therefore setting `ValidatesOnExceptions=True` in the XAML binding does not work and you need to handle errors and validate parameters manually. I'd use [Validation Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx).